# Controller is not loading in vqmod\vqcache\vq2-system_engine_controller.php

Tags: opencart, vqmod

I created a very simple module hello world.
The files i have for this module are as below with the paths.
1. admin/controller/module/helloworld.php.
2. admin/language/english/module/helloworld.php.
3. admin/view/template/module/helloworld.tpl

Module is showing and working fine in admin. But when i go to the layout where i set the module at the front side i get error.
For example when i set the layout as account and go to the account page i get the error:

Notice: Error: Could not load controller module/helloworld! in C:\xampp\htdocs\oc-1.5.6.4\vqmod\vqcache\vq2-system_engine_controller.php on line 47

Why is that? the default modules of opencart are working fine.
I cleared vqmod cache manually and using vqmod manager, nothing working.
I'm using opencart version 1.5.6.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things to check:

1. Do you have files for your module in frontend? (In your question you have mentioned only about admin panel files)
2. Verify the frontend file names and module controller class name.
3. Make sure your frontend files have read permission.

Comment: Actually i'm very new in opencart, just trying to develop a module, i forgot i actually need to create files for front end( i believe which are in module folders of controller, language, view folders of catalog folder). Can you suggest any site/sites where i can learn opencart development? there is actually no such tutorials of opencart development, all are about how to manage the site for admin.